# nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Tags: nginx-config

I try to start the nginx service but I can't, the error below occurs:

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "automx" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com.conf:3

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

The file `autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com.conf` looks like this:

```
# This file was automatically installed on 2019-12-03T13:36:48.159287 
upstream automx { 
  server unix:/run/uwsgi/app/automx_instance/socket fail_timeout=0; 
} 

server { 
  listen 80; 
  listen [::]:80; 
  server_name autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com; 
  root /srv/automx/instance; 
  access_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com-access.log; 
  error_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com-error.log; 
  location /mail/config-v1.1.xml { include uwsgi_params; uwsgi_pass automx; } 
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com.conf` file please.

Comment: # This file was automatically installed on 2019-12-03T13:36:48.159287
 upstream automx{
    server unix:/run/uwsgi/app/automx_instance/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com;
    root /srv/automx/instance;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.mod.bangalore2.com-error.log;

    location /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass automx;
    }
}

Comment: Do you have another configuration file included that also defines an upstream with the name 'automx'? That seems to be what the error is indicating?

Comment: I was installing modoba,after installation its showing this error

Comment: upstream automx {
    server unix:/run/uwsgi/app/automx_instance/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name autoconfig.bangalore2.com;
    root /srv/automx/instance;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.bangalore2.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/autoconfig.bangalore2.com-error.log;

    location /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass automx;
    }
}

Comment: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mod.bangalore2.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mod.bangalore2.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file).    Now its showing this error.

Comment: So there is a second configuration file that also defines an upstream called automx?

Comment: yes,it was not working so i installed it again

Comment: But now when i did a fresh installation its showing this error....                                                          
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mod.bangalore2.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mod.bangalore2.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file).

Comment: Possibly this: https://github.com/modoboa/modoboa-installer/issues/95

Comment: thank you...the link you shared shows same issuses with me